# Chrome looping over 206 request/response when playing Video

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, chromecast

I've been working on Chromecast application, but have run into an issue that seems to be with Chrome itself. In any manner of playing an MP4 file (either with a VIDEO tag or directly from a URL) Chrome will get about 30 minutes in and begin "skipping" by issue consecutive 206 requests but not waiting for response. This happens from when serving locally, from another machine, or just opening the file in Chrome with "File/Open". Its hard to believe its really a bug in Chrome so I am wondering if anybody has seen this issue and if it has anything to do with server setup.